# To find radius of convergence of the power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

What is radius of convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ({\log n})^2 (z^{n})$

I know that for a holomorphic function $f$ whose power series has coefficient $a_n$ is given as

$\frac{1}{R}= \lim_{x \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$

Using this I am stuck in the step 
$\frac{1}{R}= \lim_{x \to \infty} |\frac{\log({n+1})}{\log n}|$
, Please help.

Comment: the square is on the whole or just on  $n$??

Comment: Yes, The square is on the whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for $\frac{1}{R}$ in the last line is wrong — why is $a_n$ still there? There's the general formula, but when you use it for a specific series, both $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ must be replaced by the corresponding expressions from the given series.

In this example: $a_n=(\log n)^2$ and $a_{n+1}=(\log(n+1))^2$. (And I'm presuming $\log$ stands for the natural logarithm, although that doesn't really matter.) So
$$\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(\log(n+1))^2}{(\log n)^2}\right|=1,$$
where the limit can be found e.g. using L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: I agree with your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Radius of Convergence should be 1. The problem with your last line is that you are putting  ${a_n}$ again with ${log}$ term .The log term is itself your${ a_n}$